# Passing a classname using variable

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to search this but didn't get the workable solution, I am newbie in Jquery, I was creating multiple choice quiz and I want to disable the radio button for one question once user selects one answer for that I am giving same class name to each input and when I am using the classname in below code I am getting desired result. if class name is q1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $(".q1 :input").prop("disabled", true);
          });
```

I want to do this for multiple questions so when I am trying to pass the class name through a variable.

```
var val1 = $("input[type='radio']:checked").attr('class');
```

I get the name of class in variable val1 but not sure how to use it in jquery for the above code to work.
Could somebody please help me.  I tried many solutions on the net but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable all input elements with the classname `val1` you can do it like this:

```
$("." + val1).prop("disabled", true);
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on("click", function() {
    var val1 = $(this).attr('class');
    $("." + val1).prop("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="q1"/>Answer 1
<input type="radio" class="q1"/>Answer 2
<input type="radio" class="q1"/>Answer 3<br>
<input type="radio" class="r1"/>Answer 1
<input type="radio" class="r1"/>Answer 2
<input type="radio" class="r1"/>Answer 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer this code is giving desired result only issue is when first radio button is clicked it does not disable it and allows one more try that is only for first input after that it works

Comment: @Harshad I can't reproduce this issue, in above example it's also working for the first input.

Comment: Thank you very much @matthias_h, it is working perfectly fine now

Comment: I have one more question on similar line, if user selects incorrect answer I want to highlight the correct answer for that I am getting the id of correct answer in variable "ca" , it is getting the correct value but when I am using it in below code I am not getting any output
$("label[for=' + ca ']").css("background-color","green"); 
I have tried multiple options like variable without any quotes or double quotes inside single quotes but nothing worked.

Comment: @Harshad Try $("label[for=" + ca + "]").css("backgroundColor","green");

Comment: Hey @matthias_h , thank you very much buddy, sorry to bother you again could you please help me to solve probably last puzzle in the series, as I got the class name using var class1 = $(this).attr('class') ;   now I am getting id of correct answer if classname is q1  using this code: var ca = $('input[value="correct"].q1').attr('id') ; but when I am using variable in place of q1 getting errors $('input[value="correct"]"." + class1 + ').attr('id') ;

Comment: @Harshad This works for me: var ca = $('input[value="correct"].' + class1).attr('id');